# Android Firebase ChildEventListener returns multiple copies of same data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fragment

using firebase addChildEventListener in fragments for displaying data in recycleview that has been changed in realtime database. but each time i move from one fragment to another and return to the fragment with addChildEventListener multiple listeners are added which results in duplicate copies of same data.

public class list extends Fragment {
     ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;

```
private RecyclerView recyclerViewUsers;
private ArrayList<Team> listUsers;
public static recycleview_adapter usersRecyclerAdapter;
private SQLiteDBHelper databaseHelper;
private SQLiteDBHelper sqd;
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("teams");

public list() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sqd = new SQLiteDBHelper(getActivity());
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // myRef.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
    if(mChildEventListener != null) {
        myRef.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    }
    mChildEventListener =myRef.child("teams").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            Team1 newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Team1.class);
            System.out.println("Name: " + newPost.name);
            System.out.println("Points: " + newPost.Points);
            System.out.println(" ID: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            Team1 newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Team1.class);
            System.out.println("Name: " + newPost.name);
            System.out.println("Points: " + newPost.Points);
            System.out.println("ID : " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            sqd.InsertData(newPost.name,Integer.parseInt(newPost.Points));
            if(list.super.isVisible()) {
                initObjects();
            }


        }


        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    recyclerViewUsers = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewUsers);


    initObjects();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if(mChildEventListener != null) {
        myRef.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    }
}

private void initObjects() {
    listUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    usersRecyclerAdapter = new recycleview_adapter(listUsers);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerViewUsers.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerViewUsers.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewUsers.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerViewUsers.setAdapter(usersRecyclerAdapter);
    databaseHelper = new SQLiteDBHelper(getActivity());
    //divider
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerViewUsers.getContext(),
            linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
    recyclerViewUsers.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    //
    getDataFromSQLite();
}


private void getDataFromSQLite() {
    // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation not blocks the UI Thread.
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            databaseHelper = new SQLiteDBHelper(getActivity());
            listUsers.clear();
            listUsers.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllUser());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            usersRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mChildEventListener != null) {
        myRef.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to remove previous event listener before attaching a new listener.

```
databaseRef.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
```

You can remove the listener inside the `onDetach()` method

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    databaseRef.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
}
```

Comment: tried it but it doesnt solve my problem i have included the code above

Answer (score 0):

try `setAdapter(null)` then load data again or `saveState` **fragment**

Comment: once the data is changed in server it is saved into the local sqlite db then the recycleview loads the data